# How to implement a picture wall with an iPhone

Tags: iphone, coverflow, facebook-wall

http://img2.mtime.com/mg/2010/2/a3862303-825b-4adc-a3f8-e7b95d00b507.jpg

I just want to know how to implement the 3D wall that the picture above shows.

Could anybody give me some tips?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [**Flow Cover**](http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m)